# Returning an Unsubscribe and Array from a JavaScript function for Firebase Snapshot Listener in Svelte

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, svelte

I have a SvelteKit project that uses Firebase Firestore. I have a db.js file that has a number of functions I use in Svelte components. One example is shown below.

```
export const Items = {
    async getMany() {
        let dbRef = db.collection('items')

        try {
            const snap = await dbRef.get()
            return snap.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('Error')
        }
    },
},
```

Then in the svelte component onMount I call the following and set items equal to the result.

```
let items = []

onMount(() => {
    Items.getMany().then(res => {
       if (res.length != 0) {
       items = res
}})
```

This works well.

I am trying to create a function in db.js that allows me to use a snapshot listener with onSnapshot from Firebase Firestore. I’d like to return the unsubscribe function and the array of items. How would I rewrite Items.getMany() to return both unsubscribe and an array of items that I could set in the svelte component like shown below.

```
let items = []
let unsubscribe = function () {
    return
}

onMount(() => {
    Items.getMany().then(res => {
       unsubscribe = res.unsubscribe
       if (res.length != 0) {
           items = res
    }})
})
```

I've written this directly in the component as shown below and it works well. I can't get it to work when using db.js. I've tried returning an object with { unsubscribe, items } but it won't work. Any help would be appreciated.

```
let unsubscribe = function () {
        return
    }
    let items = []

onMount(() => {
        Items.getMany().then(res => {

        let dbRef = db.collection('items')

        unsubscribe = dbRef.onSnapshot(snapshot => {
            items = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id }))
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `async/await` method to get both the `unsubscribe` function and an `array of items` from the `Items.getMany()` function.

For example:

```
async getMany() {
    let dbRef = db.collection('items')

    try {
        const snap = await dbRef.get()
        const items = snap.docs.map(doc => ({
            ...doc.data(),
            id: doc.id
        }))

        // Create the unsubscribe function
        let unsubscribe = () => {
            dbRef.offSnapshot(snapshot => {
                items = snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({
                    ...doc.data(),
                    id: doc.id
                }))
            })
        }

        return {
            items,
            unsubscribe
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.log('Error')
    }
},
}
```

The `async/wait` method lets you wait for the resolution of the `dbRef.get()` promise before providing the result. The `getMany()` function then constructs an item array from the snap.docs collection.

Then in the Svelte component, you can use the items and unsubscribe variables as shown in the example below:

```
let items = []
let unsubscribe = null

onMount(async () => {
    const result = await Items.getMany()
    items = result.items
    unsubscribe = result.unsubscribe
})

onDestroy(() => {
    if (unsubscribe) {
        unsubscribe()
    }
})
```

Reference for Async/Await method: [How Does Async/Await Work in JavaScript](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/async-await-in-javascript/#:%7E:text=Async%2FAwait%20makes%20it%20easier,wait%20until%20the%20Promise%20resolves.)